# AWS API in R - Added Authorization Header but getting InvalidSignatureException

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, api, post

I am trying to use AWS API in R. I am using R so that i can add it to an exisiting ShinyApp (which is a web application build in R).
This API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_GetCurrentMetricData.html
Using signature version 4:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

I have added the 'Authorization' details to the header as per AMZ documentation, and  the exact header works perfectly in python, but strangely not in R and returns an error saying 'InvalidSignatureException'.

My guess is that i have got something wrong with the variables in the POST function. I've quite a few different arrangements of the POST variables to try and get it to work but nothing seems to help.

This is the python code which works:

```py
import requests

url = "https://connect.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/metrics/current/XXXXXXX"

payload = "{\r\n    \"InstanceId\" : \"XXXXXXX\",\r\n    \"Filters\" : {\r\n        \"Queues\" : [\r\n            \"XXXXXXX\",\r\n            \"arn:aws:connect:eu-central-1:XXXXXXX:instance/XXXXXXX/queue/XXXXXXX\"\r\n        ]\r\n    },\r\n    \"CurrentMetrics\" : [\r\n      {\r\n          \"Name\" : \"AGENTS_ONLINE\",\r\n          \"Unit\" : \"COUNT\"\r\n      },\r\n      {\r\n          \"Name\" : \"AGENTS_AVAILABLE\",\r\n          \"Unit\" : \"COUNT\"\r\n      },\r\n      {\r\n          \"Name\" : \"OLDEST_CONTACT_AGE\",\r\n          \"Unit\" : \"SECONDS\"\r\n      },\r\n      {\r\n          \"Name\": \"AGENTS_ERROR\",\r\n          \"Unit\": \"COUNT\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n}\r\n  "
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'X-Amz-Content-Sha256': "XXXXXXX",
    'Host': "connect.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
    'X-Amz-Date': "20190724T162517Z",
    'Authorization': "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXX/20190724/eu-central-1/connect/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=XXXXXXX",
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

My attempt to write in R. (returns x-amzn-ErrorType: InvalidSignatureException)

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

request_body_json <- 
  '{
    "InstanceId" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "Filters" : {
        "Queues" : [
            "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "arn:aws:connect:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxx:instance/xxxxxxxxxx/queue/xxxxxxxxxx"
        ]
    },
    "CurrentMetrics" : [
      {
          "Name" : "AGENTS_ONLINE",
          "Unit" : "COUNT"
      },
      {
          "Name" : "AGENTS_AVAILABLE",
          "Unit" : "COUNT"
      },
      {
          "Name" : "OLDEST_CONTACT_AGE",
          "Unit" : "SECONDS"
      },
      {
          "Name": "AGENTS_ERROR",
          "Unit": "COUNT"
      }
    ]
}'

hdrs <- list(
  'Content-Type'= "application/json",
  'X-Amz-Content-Sha256'= "XXXXXXX",
  'Host'= "connect.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
  'X-Amz-Date'= "20190724T162517Z",
  'Authorization'= "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXX/20190724/eu-central-1/connect/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=XXXXXXX"
)

a <- POST(
  url = "https://connect.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/metrics/current/xxxxxxxxxx"
  ,do.call(add_headers,hdrs)
  ,verbose(info = TRUE)
  ,body = request_body_json
  ,encode = "json"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed and added the authorisations steps in too.

```
 # Librarys used
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(aws.signature)

#gather variables
host <- "connect.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
sha <- "xxxx"
amzdate <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ",tz = "UTC")
payload <- 
  '{
    "InstanceId" : "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
    "Filters" : {
        "Queues" : [
           "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
        ]
    },

    "CurrentMetrics" : [
      {
          "Name" : "OLDEST_CONTACT_AGE",
          "Unit" : "SECONDS"
      },
      {
          "Name": "CONTACTS_IN_QUEUE",
          "Unit": "COUNT"
      }
    ]
}'

content_type <-"application/json"
url_api <-"https://connect.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/metrics/current/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
region <- "eu-central-1"
service <- "connect"
verb <- "POST"
action <- "/metrics/current/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx"
key <- "xxxx"
secret <- "xxxx"

#headers so far (can't add signature yet)
hdrs <- list('Content-Type' = content_type,
             Host = host,
             'x-amz-content-sha256' = sha,
             'x-amz-date' = amzdate)

#get v4 signature
sig <- signature_v4_auth(datetime = amzdate,
                         region = region,
                         service = service,
                         verb = verb, 
                         action = action,
                         query_args = list(), 
                         canonical_headers = hdrs, 
                         request_body = payload, 
                         key = key,
                         secret = secret, 
                         session_token = NULL, 
                         query = FALSE,
                         algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256")

#add signature header to header
auth <-  sig$SignatureHeader

a <- httr::VERB(verb = "POST"
                ,url = url_api
                ,encode = 'json'
                ,content_type_json()
                ,body = payload
                ,httr::add_headers( 
                  'Content-Type' = content_type,
                  Authorization = auth,
                  Host = host, 
                  `X-Amz-Content-Sha256` = sha, 
                  `X-Amz-Date` = amzdate)
)

results <- content(a,"parsed")
```